# Implementing Observer Design Pattern in 2 computers

Tags: design-patterns, observer-pattern

In my application, I am planning on using Observer pattern. There, it uses 2 computers.

When first computer's state updates then other computer react according to that. For example when server computer makes some update, clients have to notice that, by being notified.
For that I need to Observer Code in first computer and Listener code in 2nd computer.

Is it possible to implementing Observer design pattern in 2 computers? How?

Comment: For example when server computer make some update client have to notify that.

Comment: You seldom need to comment on your own question, you should just edit it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options that you have :

1. Design your own client-server publish/subscribe library
2. Reuse existing libraries that allow you to publish/subscribe to events in a client-server applicaiton.

This answer will be limited to option (2). While there may be many other libraries available to achieve this, the following options are what come to mind from past experiences :

1. Use the publish/subscribe model provided by the [Java Messaging Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service) APIs.
2. Use the publish/subscribe model provided by [Guava EventBus](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/eventbus/EventBus.html)

Note that this answer is limited to **Java libraries**. If your language of choice does not support such APIs, you can still take a look at these libraries to get an idea of what goes into designing a publish/subscribe API.